# Exporting and Importing symbols from DLLs using DEF files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am facing the following problem:
I have DLL1 that links with a whole lot of static libs but does not export anything and the executable links only with DLL1.
I am trying to add a second DLL2 that uses some of the functionality from static libs that DLL1 links with, but the constraint is that all singletons from this static should be shared between the 2 DLL's

Since we are talking about a huge codebase, I cannot go around and do a dllimport/export in all the headers.
I saw that DEF files might be useful.

I was able to export all the symbols using some scripting magic, but am unable to use the DEF file for "dllimport" part.
As per this badly written article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54xsd65y.aspx
it should be possible to import using DEFs, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

As a conclusion:
I need to share all instances from the common code inside the 2 DLLs and cannot do dllimport/dllexport
Anybody has an Idea how this could happen.

Comment: You cannot use a .def file to expose static data.  The dllexport attribute is necessary to get the linker to generate a pointer to the data, the pointer value is relocatable and automatically gets adjusted when the DLL can't be loaded at its preferred base address.  Likewise, dllimport is necessary to tell the compiler to use that pointer. "Can't do it" usually means "don't want to do it", you perhaps ought to be a bit worried about having so much static data.  The alternative is to add accessor functions that you can export that returns a pointer to the data.

Comment: There's not that much static data. Mostly just singletons that are defined inside the static lib and painstakingly initialized by DLL1. I could go around and change the headers to expose the correct functionality. The big problem stems from the fact that all errors are silent, thus you cannot know wha else did i miss.